# I cant download and use any npm package

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

when I trying install hooks or npm packages, npm installer is run and complete successfully but when I want use hooks or packages, I'm getting an

> package not found error

Why am I getting this error? could this error be the npm version? do you have any idea about the cause of this error?

Comment: How do you add these package? Could you give examples of the `npm` command you are using and the code that loads the packages?

Answer (score 0):

If the download is Successful:
use the command *npm*  to check if your package is successfully installed or not . If it does it shows some command usage of npm.

Now Suppose it shows successful installation but you aren't able use it ,then most probably you aren't installing the package in the right directory where your .js files are existing .
It would be really helpful if you could share more information of the errors !!